# How to abort large file upload with OkHttp?

Tags: java, okhttp

I am using OkHttp 3.1.2. 
I've created file upload similar to the original recipe which is found here: https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/PostMultipart.java

I can't find example how to abort an upload of large file upon user request. I mean not how to get the user request but how to tell the OkHttp to stop sending data. 
So far the only solution that I can imagine is to use custom `RequestBody`, add an `abort()` method and override the `writeTo()` method like this:

```
public void abort() {
    aborted = true;
}

@Override
public void writeTo(BufferedSink sink) throws IOException {
    Source source = null;
    try {
        source = Okio.source(mFile);
        long transferred = 0;
        long read;

        while (!aborted && (read = source.read(sink.buffer(), SEGMENT_SIZE)) != -1) {
            transferred += read;
            sink.flush();
            mListener.transferredSoFar(transferred);

        }
    } finally {
        Util.closeQuietly(source);
    }
}
```

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out it is quite easy:

Just hold reference to the `Call` object and cancel it when needed like this:

```
private Call mCall;


private void executeRequest (Request request) {
    mCall = mOkHttpClient.newCall(request);
    try {
        Response response = mCall.execute();
        ...
    } catch (IOException e) {
        if (!mCall.isCanceled()) {
            mLogger.error("Error uploading file: {}", e);
            uploadFailed(); // notify whoever is needed
        }
    }
}


public void abortUpload() {
    if (mCall != null) {
        mCall.cancel();
    }
}
```

Please note that when you cancel the `Call` while uploading an `IOException` will be thrown so you have to check in the `catch` if it is cancelled (as shown above) otherwise you will have false positive for error.

I think the same approach can be used for aborting download of large files.